# What LEGO sets/blocks to buy?

Tags: shopping

We plan to buy some lego (up to $200) for a charity that helps homeless children in India. Kids in the charity's homes are of all ages (2-18). Kids are very creative but obviously lack resources. I'm hoping LEGO can be very stimulating for them.

I'm wondering what are the best starter LEGOs that can be played in multiple ways and attract children from all age groups.

I can 1 lb Lego packs from eBay and also some pricey sets at Amazon. I want to get best value for money. I have only 10 days before I fly to India so need to know asap where I can buy from and what.

Many thanks
NG

Comment: One thought is to take some boxes of something like this. Is that a good idea? http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-Classic-Medium-Creative-Brick/dp/B00NHQFA1I/ref=sr_1_1?s=toys-and-games&ie=UTF8&qid=1449438411&sr=1-1&keywords=lego+bulk

Comment: I'd also look for second hand Lego to bulk things up and also give kids something to play with that doesn't have instructions. Some schools are very into teaching obedience and need a bit of prompting to let students be creative.

Comment: Nothing with guns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend one of the new lego city starter packs/sets. It is usually a mix of two or more lego city sub themes!

Answer (score 3):

Different kids are motivated by different kinds of sets. Some kids need directed building to focus them, and so a set with instructions helps them. Other kids just need useful parts.

I'd recommend getting basic bricks to start, something from the Classic line. Or else get something from the Creator line, many of those sets come with instructions for alternate models. This is a good lesson on how the same inventory of pieces can make more than one set. On [Lego's Website](http://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Creator-ByTheme) you can check the set descriptions for Creator sets that are "3 in 1".

Larger sets will cost more, but the models will be more challenging and will offer more opportunity to build more things (as it's usually easier to build things if you have more pieces).

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at 10696 from classic range. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: 10696 is fine. It contains a little of this, a little of that. It's a good assortment to get started. It has enough pieces for one big model or several small ones. Since this is for a group to pay with rather than one child to own, the lack of instructions is fine and probably good as they'd get lost anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping to get 7-8 boxes of that so multiple things can come up.

Comment: Any thoughts on Brictec. It seems cheaper but not sure what all pieces it has.

Comment: I don't know brictec. Generally I avoid the other brands as I find the quality isn't as high. Also, if you're planning to mix together the bricks from multiple sets, buying fewer larger sets usually gets you more pieces than more smaller sets would.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting attention to Creator 3-in-1 series.

It might be good idea to print out alternative MOC instructions to the sets you buy as well (some can be found on rebrickable.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest basic bricks since those last long. Sets like 6177 might be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. 6177 seems very expensive. I want to maximize value for money. Do you know how t differs from 10696 as that is 485 pieces for $29. Also any thoughts on Brictec?